# Handle Mono.empty() in GatewayFilter

Tags: project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm building a GatewayFilter, but I'm having problems handling cases where I don't have data.  Here is a sample of the GatewayFilterFactory<>:

```
    return (exchange, chain) -> getDataFromRedis()
        .flatMap(redisData -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                .header("header", redisData).build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        });
```

Here is the `getDataFromRedis` method:

```
Mono<String> getDataFromRedis() {
    return redis.get("key");
}
```

It returns a Mono with a String value, or empty if it wasn't found.

The above example works as expected, but when the data is redis is not found, and an empty Mono is returned, then I need it to return a redirect.  So this is my attempt:

```
    return (exchange, chain) -> getDataFromRedis()
        .flatMap(redisData -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                .header("header", redisData).build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "some other url");
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }));
```

The deferred mono in `switchIfEmpty` is always invoked, irrespective of whether there is data in redis or not.

To summarise, I need the filter to add a header value it gets from Redis, but redirect if there is no data available.

Comment: your last snippet is unclear: what is `getAuthToken`? There's no visible call to `getDataFromRedis` there. Also, in `getDataFromRedis` the whole `switchIfEmpty` can be removed, as it does basically nothing (if the source is empty, it is already equivalent to `Mono.empty()`)

Comment: Removed the redundant .switchIfEmpty and renamed the .getAuthToken, which was there because of copy/paste.

Comment: Mmh that is weird then, no reason for switchIfEmpty to trigger if getDataFromRedis emits something. Have you tried adding a `.log()` to better see what's coming through?

Comment: As far as I can tell there are more Mono,s attached to the one you return from the apply method, so there might be something not working correctly.  For now I'm returning Mono<Optional<String>> around so I don't have to deal with empty Mono's, but I cringe every time I open the file.